# Setting background image with respect to a point in Paraview

Tags: visualization

How to set image with respect to a point in Paraview? I have a vtk file within a rectangular domain starting with the lower left point -1842,10000, I want to set a background image whose lower left also starts at the same point as stated earlier in order to superimpose the vtk on the image. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to apply a transform filter to each item and translate it anyway you need.

You can enter the translate values directly in the properties tab. Or you can middle-mouse and drag the object into position.

Comment: yes I tried that, but whenever I use transform the whole system literally stops, I am trying to transform an image of size 3.8MB PNG compressed from 478MB.

Comment: If you think the system should be able to handle the final result, then first change the view to "Outline" and then position it. When you are done switch it back.

Comment: I will try that out